# Python: Change the label of a matplotlib button on click

Tags: python, button, matplotlib, label

How do you change the label of a matplotlib button on clicking it? Like if I have a matplotlib button with the label "Before", I want to click it and change the label to "After". How do I do this? I feel that I should know this but I really can't find anything on this online or in the documentation.

Comment: You capture the click event, then programatically change the label.  Event handling here: http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/users/event_handling.html

Comment: How would you "programmatically change the label"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

assuming this example http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/examples/widgets/buttons.html

```
bprev.label="A new Label!" #actually this doesnt work...
```

I figured this out with next to no knowledge of buttons simply by looking at the docs (really just glancing at them)  http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/api/widgets_api.html#Button

a little more experimentation led me to

```
bprive.label.set_text("A new label") # works
```

Comment: you probably have to have interactive mode on `ion()` I think ... or it would not actually update the image

Comment: didn't work either. Maybe I'll try something else. Thanks for the answers!

Comment: @lkloh see edit :P  apparently i was wrong initially

Comment: I needed to call `plt.draw()` after for the change to take effect.